# Massless Sunset Diagram $\phi^4$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-regularization

I should compute an explicit calculation for the **sunset diagram** in **massless** $\phi^4$ theory.

The integral is $$-\lambda^2 \frac{1}{6} (\mu)^{2(4-d)}\int \frac{d^dk_1}{(2\pi)^d} \int \frac{d^dk_2}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{1}{(k_1^2+i\eta)(k_2^2+i\eta)((p+k_1+k_2)^2+i\eta)}$$
using the $(+,-,-,-)$ Minkowski sign convention.

The hint is to compute the integrals with Feynman Parametrization but I'm having some problems.

Comment: Using Feynman parameters - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization

Answer (score 3):

It's much easier in real space:
$$
I[k] = \int d^dx [G(x,0)]^3 e^{ikx}
$$
with the massless (Euclidean) propagator
$$
G(x,0) = \frac{1} {2^d \pi^{d/2}} \Gamma(d/2-1) (4/|x|^2)^{n/2-1}.
$$
Use
$$
 \int \frac{d^n x}{(2\pi)^n} e^{ik\cdot x } |x^2|^s = \frac{4^s}{\pi^{n/2}}\frac{\Gamma(s+n/2)}{\Gamma(-s)} \frac{1}{|k|^{2s+n}}
$$
to
evaluate the Fourier transform in Euclidean signature and then continue the momentum $k$ to Minkowski.